# Get object by id using Mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections:

1. Movies
 2. Actors

I am using aggregate to find the movies in which an actor is as follows:

```
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{

const peliculaActor = await Actores.aggregate([

    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
   }
 ])

 res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

This works, but if an actor does not have movies also brings it into the result.

I need to do something like this so that it only brings me the result for the object id.

```
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{

const peliculaActor = await Actores.findById(req.params.id).aggregate([

    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
   }
 ])

 res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

But I get:

> TypeError: Actors.findById (...). Aggregate is not a function

All this is necessary to obtain Mestro-Detail using ActivateRoute in Angular.

I hope your help friends.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$match` operator of aggregate pipeline for filter to the collection.
Look like -

```
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{

const peliculaActor = await Actores.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: req.params.id,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
   }
 ])

 res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for replying, I receive an empty array                                                   / 20191118173243
// http://localhost:3000/api/peliculas/actores/peliculas/5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3

[
  
]